# Scrollto with separated link and Menu (current page position)

Tags: jquery, position, background-color, scrollto

I'm trying to make a single website : http://www.ubik-agency.com/test/t-e-s-t/

I use a Menu Script (One Page Nav) based on scrollto, to navigate. But this script works only with a single menu. When I'm using it with other free links on the page, I lose the Menu State (page position state), in other words the current class doesn't function anymore, even if I use a different current classes for the links.

I would also find a script changing my menu (header) background, in function of the page position, and this slowly (with a transition time).

I'm waiting for your help and answer!

Answer (score 0):

Here the result, http://www.ubik-agency.com/, I used scrollTo to manage the separated links, and changed the header, to keep its color unique.

waiting your comments!